# Compiling multiple DSC configurations on Azure Automation Account in parallel

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I have several DSC configurations on my Automation Account. When I compile them separately everything is fine but if I run 2 or more compilation at the same time, it happens that some of the compilations fail with different errors similar to following:

> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Client\Temp\tempconfig\946ab078-a97f-45ee-b6a5-5d24bd76489d\' because it does not exist.

or

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. (Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.)

or

> Cannot index into a null array. (Cannot index into a null array.)

My configuration is as easy as this:

```
Configuration TempConfig
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node 'localhost' {
        WindowsFeature InstallDotNetFrameworkCore
        {
            Ensure = 'Present'
            Name = 'NET-Framework-Core'
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I compile the same configuration multiple times as well as when I compile different multiple configurations (but as simple as the one above).
There is really no rule and I get those errors randomly.
Is this some kind of limitation from Azure or an I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I do think you need to address that question to the Azure Automation Team ;) Or hope that some of them will find this question ;)

Comment: Yep I've contacted Azure support and they are working on that but hoped someone already faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Loku,

Are you using collections in your config?

Are you getting these errors when you compile the same configuration multiple times simultaneously?

> > Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. (Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.)
> >
> > Cannot index into a null array. (Cannot index into a null array.)

Is it possible for you to provide configuration script (without any secrets)?

Comment: I have updated my post. In short - it happen in both cases (compiling the same configuration multiple times and compiling different configurations at the same time) and my configurations are super simple, nothing about collections or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem and the solution is to use the dependsOn attribute in the configuration resources to effectively chain them together s they execute serially rather than in parallel.

Here's an example

```
    {
      "name": "[variables('dscConfigurations').DomainJoinConfig.name]",
      "type": "configurations",
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('AutomationAccountName')]",
        "dscDomainAdmin"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "state": "Published",
        "overwrite": "true",
        "source": {
          "type": "uri",
          "value": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), variables('dscConfigurations').DomainJoinConfig.script, parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('dscConfigurations').AddServerRolesAndFeaturesArchive.name]",
      "type": "configurations",
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('AutomationAccountName')]",
        "[variables('dscResources').xPendingReboot.name]",
        "[variables('dscConfigurations').DomainJoinConfig.name]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "state": "Published",
        "overwrite": "true",
        "source": {
          "type": "uri",
          "value": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), variables('dscConfigurations').AddServerRolesAndFeaturesArchive.script, parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('dscConfigurations').AddServerRoleAndFeaturesContent.name]",
      "type": "configurations",
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('AutomationAccountName')]",
        "[variables('dscResources').xPendingReboot.name]",
        "[variables('dscConfigurations').AddServerRolesAndFeaturesArchive.name]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "state": "Published",
        "overwrite": "true",
        "source": {
          "type": "uri",
          "value": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), variables('dscConfigurations').AddServerRoleAndFeaturesContent.script, parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
        }
      }
    },
```